# I can make a http post on android emulator but can't in cell phone

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

i'm sending a post using this code:

```
try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imagem", "1"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
v.setEnabled(true);
```

it works fine on my emulator. I have already searched on other posts how to solve this and what i have found was something about the android manifest having internet permission.
Here is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="imp.projecto.teste.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityImagem" />
    <activity android:name=".ActivityVideo" />
    <activity android:name=".ActivityMusica" />
    <activity android:name=".ActivityRadio" />
    <activity android:name=".ActivityOpcoes" />

</application>
```

I have no idea if i used the internet permission code in the right place and if it is doing it's job.
I really need some help and some orientation.

Comment: If there is an error or exception please provide some log output

Comment: whats your question. is your app works in emulator and not on android real device? is that so?

Comment: clean your project, restart the phone and try again.

Comment: How about a log statement in your catch blocks? How in gods name should you be able to see your app throwing exceptions when you just swallow them?

Comment: @WarrenFaith, I'm pretty sure it's a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: well the thing is that on the emulator i can send the posto and my php server recive it. 
when i try to run the emulation on my phone it does not give any kind of error or exception and the server does not recieve the post

Comment: `on my phone it does not give any kind of error or exception` *hard breathing* because you just SWALLOW them! Put `Log.e(TAG, "message", e);` in your catch blocks! Seriously! NEVER EVER write empty catch blocks in a development version of your app!

Comment: k i'l give it a try thanks for the input :D

Comment: ok i have tryed it again and it gives an exception:
java.net.socketException: no root to host

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to run a network request on the main UI thread. Android does not allow you to do that since 3.0 (I believe). Doing so causes your UI to lock up until the request is completed, rendering your app useless during the execution of the request.

You'll either have to run your request in a new `Thread` or an `ASyncTask`, to take the load of the UI thread. You can find more info on how to use multiple threads [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: thanks for the input but that's not the real problem, because i'm runing it in android 2.2. My problem  is that when i'm running my app in the emulator 2.2 all works fine, but when i try to run the emulator in my phone witch is android 2.3.4 the posts stop working and the app does not give any error or excetion.

Comment: Well... You're not doing anything with the Exceptions it throws in the code you posted so that might explain why you don't see any errors. You catch them, but you don't handle them.